# UIImage to Base64 string problem. Space under image when decoded

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, base64

I converted an `UIImage` to Base64 string. When other service decode it to `UIImage` a huge space just below the image can be seen.

**I use this method to convert from `UIImage` to Base64:**

```
func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String {        
    let jpegCompressionQuality: CGFloat = 0.5
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, jpegCompressionQuality)
    let base64String = imageData?.base64EncodedString()

    return base64String!
}
```

Decoding on simulator - view background color is black:

**see the image here**

[image: Screen Shot]

The white space below the image can be seen in this decode example when the background of the view is black.

Can anyone give me a hint to avoid it?

Comment: You should also include the original image and your decoding method in your question along with your code for displaying the decoded image.

Comment: Hi Dávid decoding is being done by a third party web service. I decoded it creating a new iOS app just to get the same problem reported. I decoded using 2 lines:

Comment: let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageString, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
        return UIImage(data: imageData)!

Comment: Isn't this the bottom bar of the iPhone X ?

Comment: Hi Marwen, as I said this base64 is decoded by a web service. In the sample I created I used simulator to create a black view and in the middle of it I added UIImageVIew to display the image. the white in the image is part of the decoded UIImage in iOS simulator app. The same happens in the web service that decodes it :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't seen the full image.

Comment: Are you sure the white is part of the image. Why don't you write the resulting image data instead of displaying in an UIImageView and check if the actual result has the white space on it or not.

Comment: Are you sure that encoded image without white space?

Comment: @LeoDabus this image comes with the photo library of Xcode 10.1. You can check it by yourself you just need to run the simulator and open the Photos app, for instance. The major issues resides on the method used to generate base64 string. It happens for any image. If I run my code in a real device and take a picture the same will happen. The question here is the method itself to save the base64 string :)

Comment: I convinced my 3rd party web service manager to avoid base64. Instead of that I'll upload an image as NSData :)

Answer (score -1):

I convinced my 3rd party web service manager to avoid base64. Instead of that I'll upload an image as NSData :)
***Issue solved*** :)